# Populate 2d sub-array by passing it as a function argument

Tags: arrays, c, 2d

I have an `int **test [50]` array, where memory is created dynamically for the 5th element of the 50 available elements, to create a single instance of a 2d sub-array of 10 x 7.

In the example below I want to populate the sub-array using the `fill()` function, then print the values of the populated sub-array.

Unfortunately it doesn't work and I don't know why. Compiler won't show up anything but program crashes.

```
#define NUM_OF_ELEMENTS     7

void fill(int outp[][NUM_OF_ELEMENTS], int no_elements)
{
    int tmp = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < no_elements;i++)
    {
        outp[i][0] = tmp++;
        outp[i][1] = tmp++;
        outp[i][2] = tmp++;
        outp[i][3] = tmp++;
        outp[i][4] = tmp++;
        outp[i][5] = tmp++;
        outp[i][6] = tmp++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int iter = 5;
    int array_length = 10;
    int **test[50];

    test[iter] = malloc(sizeof(*test[iter]) * array_length);

    for(int i = 0;i < array_length;i++)
    {
        test[iter][i] = malloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS * sizeof(*test[iter][0]));
    }

    fill(test[iter], array_length);

    for(int i = 0;i < array_length;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0;j < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS;j++)
        {
            printf("test[5][%d][%d] = %d \n", i, j, test[iter][i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: An array of pointers is not the same as a 2D array.

Comment: See updated answer below.  Previous did not populate 5th element, updated content does.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 1):

***Note***, complete re-write after having re-read OP request to update only 5th element of array.

> *"Compiler won't show up anything but program crashes"*

The way the variable is typed is incompatible with the function prototype:
After creating memory for the 5th element, conceptually a `1x10x7` area of non-contiguous memory, then passing the element into the `fill()` function as shown:

```
fill(test[iter], array_length);
```

where the prototype of the `fill()` function is:

```
void fill(int outp[][NUM_OF_ELEMENTS], int no_elements);
```

should have resulted a compile warning, something to the effect:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int **' to parameter of type 'int (*)[7]'
```

Also, because the shape of memory to be populated is conceptually 10x7, the contents of the `fill()` function should contain 10 instances (not 7) of 7 columns.

These issues, have been addressed in the following adaptation of your implementation, which successfully populates the full 70 values of the 5th element:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_OF_ELEMENTS     7

void fill(int **outp[10], int no_elements)//Note new parameter syntax which 
{                                         //includes 10 (not 7) rows to be updated
        int tmp = 0;                      //and a in a form compatible with returning updated values (extra *).
        for(int i = 0;i < no_elements;i++)
        {
            (*outp)[0][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[1][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[2][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[3][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[4][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[5][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[6][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[7][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[8][i] = tmp++;
            (*outp)[9][i] = tmp++;
            
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        int iter = 5;
        int array_length = 10;
        //int **test[50];
        int **test[50];

        //Note use of calloc (rather than malloc) to avoid having to explicitly 
        //initialize memory before use as a separate step.
        test[iter] = calloc(array_length, sizeof(*test[iter]));

        for(int i = 0;i < array_length;i++)
        {
            test[iter][i] = calloc(NUM_OF_ELEMENTS , sizeof(*test[iter][0]));
        }

        //fill(test[iter], array_length);
        fill(&(test[iter]), NUM_OF_ELEMENTS);//pass the address of the 5th element to 
                                             //allow updated values to be passed back.
        
        for(int i = 0;i < array_length;i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0;j < NUM_OF_ELEMENTS;j++)
            {
                printf("test[iter][%d][%d] = %d \n", i, j, test[iter][i][j]);
            }
        }
        // now you must free all of the memory 

        
        return 0;
    }
```